# Div position of "button" depends on content height

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the sidebar where we have a logo at the top and some bottom div. The middle div "content" has overflow: scroll and contains paragraph(s). So what I need... If I have only one paragraph (or two p) the button div should be positioned absolutely at the bottom of the content and if I have more paragraphs which have a bigger height than "content" div so then the button div will have position static (so will be scrollable).

And I need it only by CSS. Is it possible?

We need IE11+ support.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tempor egestas ornare. Suspendisse potenti. Integer non euismod nulla. Quisque pretium est sit amet congue rhoncus.</p>   


    <div class="button">
      Button
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;

  background-color: grey;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;

  background-color: red;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;

  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  bottom: 100px;


  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.button { 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. Add this to your CSS:

```
.content {
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button { 
align-self: flex-end;
}
```

That will render the button always at the end of the content div.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I know about flexbox but is possible without it? and without JS?

Comment: Not that I know of. Your other option would be to give `.content p` a min-height such as 100%.